# BulletinBoard assign gesture for ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, dialog

I'm using BulletinBoard ([BLTNBoard)](https://github.com/alexisakers/BulletinBoard) to create dialogs in my iOS app. There's an option to embed image inside it. I would like to extend it's functionality and allow user to manipulate this image using tap gesture. But eventually when I assign a gesture to it's imageView using `addGestureRecognizer` nothing happens.

Here's how I initiliaze bulletin and add gesture to the image:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var bulletinManager: BLTNItemManager = {
        let rootItem: BLTNPageItem = BLTNPageItem(title: "")
        return BLTNItemManager(rootItem: rootItem)
    }()



   override func viewDidLoad() {
      //etc code
      let bulletinManager: BLTNItemManager = {
          let item = BLTNPageItem(title: "Welcome")
           
           item.descriptionText = "Pleas welcome to my app"
           item.actionButtonTitle = "Go"
           item.alternativeButtonTitle = "Try to tap here"
           item.requiresCloseButton = false
           item.isDismissable = false

           item.actionHandler = { item in
            self.bulletinManager.dismissBulletin()
           }

           item.alternativeHandler = { item in
               //do nothing by now
           }  

           //
           item.image = UIImage(named: "welcome")

           //adding gesture to its imageView
           item.imageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
           let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapTap:"))
           item.imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


           return BLTNItemManager(rootItem: item)
      }()
   }



   @objc func tapTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("TAPTAP!!!!!!")
   }

}
```

and nothing happens at all (no message printed in console).

However if I assign action inside alternative button it works as expected:

```
      item.alternativeHandler = { item in
                item.imageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
                let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapTap:"))
                item.imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
      }
```

I guess the only thing which can prevent me to assign the tap event to it properly is that imageView becomes available much later than the bulletin is created (for example only when it is shown on the screen).

Could you please help and correct my code. Thanks

**upd.**
Ok, based on Philipp's answer I have the following solution:

```
class myPageItem: BLTNPageItem {
   override func makeContentViews(with interfaceBuilder: BLTNInterfaceBuilder) -> [UIView] {
       let contentViews = super.makeContentViews(with: interfaceBuilder)
           
       let imageView=super.imageView
       
       imageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
       let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapTap))
       imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
       
       return contentViews
   }
   
   @objc func tapTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {   
       print("TAPTAP!!!!!!")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're working with an open source library, it's easy to check out the source code to find the answer.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/alexisakers/BulletinBoard/blob/7b35bb98d776f869851f345696215def30814de2/Sources/Models/BLTNPageItem.swift#L38-L42), `image` setter doesn't initiate the image view.

Both `makeContentViews` `makeArrangedSubviews` (which are responsible for views initializing) doesn't have any finish notification callbacks.

Usually in such cases I had to fork the repo and add functionality by myself - then I'll make a pull request if I think this functionality may be needed by someone else.

But luckily for you the BLTNPageItem is marked open, so you can just subclass it. Override `makeContentViews` and add your logic there, something like this:

```
class YourOwnPageItem: BLTNPageItem {
    override func makeContentViews(with interfaceBuilder: BLTNInterfaceBuilder) -> [UIView] {
        let contentViews = super.makeContentViews(with: interfaceBuilder)
        // configure the imageView here
        return contentViews
    }
}
```